# Discontinuous additive function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, metric-spaces, axiom-of-choice

I was trying to prove the following proposition. Let  $l:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}  $  be a function s.t. 
$$ 
\begin{align*}
 1. & l\left(x\right)=0  \iff  x=0 \\
 2. & l\left(x\right)  =l\left(-x\right)\\
 3. & l\left(x+y\right) \leq l\left(x\right)+l\left(y\right)\\
 4. & l\left(x+y\right)=l\left(x\right)+l\left(y\right)\iff x=\lambda y 
\end{align*} 
$$
For a $0<\lambda$. Then $l$ is the Euclidean norm. I now believe this to be false. A function $$f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$$ that is a discontinuous additive bijection s.t. for every $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$  the condition $$\exists \lambda >0 , f\left(x\right)=\lambda f\left(y\right)\iff \exists \delta >0 , x=\delta y$$ holds would be a counter example. Does a function of this sort exist?

Comment: If $x = -y \ (\lambda = -1)$ then $l(0)=l(-y)+l(y)=2\cdot l(y) = 0$ so $l(y)\equiv 0 $ is the zero function

Comment: @kingW3 The last property is suppose to hold only for $\lambda >0$. Though OP said this there is  slight typo there.

Comment: Requiring "every $x$" is a bit much. If $f(x)=2x$ and $f(y)=3y$ and $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, then $x+y$ is not colinear with $f(x+y)$.

Comment: The idea is to pull back the Euclidean metric using f and to get a weird metric on R^2. Is that condition not necessary?

Comment: Where is $\lambda$ coming from? $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb R$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ I corrected the question

Comment: As written, there is no such function $l$: Be $y=0$. Then by condition 1, $l(y)=0$. Therefore condition 4 demands that $l(x)=l(x)\iff x=0$. Which clearly cannot be true. Of course that implies that the claim that any such $l$ is the Euclidean norm is vacuously true.

Comment: take $N$ to be any norm and $l_2$ the euclidean norm. Then $l:=N+l_2$ is a norm so satisfies 1 through 3 and the reverse implication of 4; and if $l(x+y) = l(x)+l(y)$ then by the triangle inequality for both $N$ and $l_2$ we get in particular that $l_2(x+y)=l_2(x)+l_2(y)$. Then this implies that $x,y$ are positively  bound, by usual properties of the euclidean norm. However, if $N\neq \lambda l_2$, $l$ will not be a multiple of $l_2$.